# Spring: Register a component within a test class

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test

I am registering an `ErrorHandler` for my Spring `Scheduler` and would like to test that is is correctly registered in a `SpringTest`

So far I have tried:

**Handler**

```
@Component
public class ScheduledErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    @Autowired
    private ErrorService errorService;

    @Override
    public void handleError(final Throwable t) {
        errorService.handle(t);
    }

}
```

**Registering the Handler**

```
@EnableScheduling
@Configuration
public class SchedulingConfiguration implements SchedulingConfigurer { 

    @Autowired
    private ScheduledErrorHandler handler;

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        final ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        scheduler.setPoolSize(1);
        scheduler.setErrorHandler(handler);
        scheduler.initialize();
        taskRegistrar.setScheduler(scheduler);
    }

    //...
}
```

**Testing it's registered**

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
    SchedulerConfiguration.class,
    SchedulerErrorHandler.class
})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class SchedulerErrorHandlerTest {

    @MockBean
    private ErrorService service;

    @Autowired
    private ExampleScheduledJob job;

    @Test
    public void verifyHandlerGetsCalled() {
        // Wait until the job runs
        if(!job.latch.await(5, SECONDS)) {
            fail("Job never ran");
        }

        verify(service).handle(any(RuntimeException.class));
    }

    @Component
    public static class ExampleScheduledJob {
        private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        @Scheduled(fixedRate=1000)
        public void run() {
            latch.countDown();
            throw new RuntimeException("error");
        }
    }
}
```

However when I do this I get a `DependencyNotFound` error saying Spring cannot create my test class as no Bean named `ExampleScheduledJob` can be found. How can I register it **only** for the sake of this test?

> Error creating bean with name
>   'com.example.demo.SchedulerErrorHandlerTest': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'job'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'com.example.demo.SchedulerErrorHandlerTest$ExampleScheduledJob'
>   available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Comment: One important thing I noticed was the inner class **must**  be `static`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
        SchedulingConfiguration.class,
        SchedulerErrorHandlerTest.ExampleScheduledJob.class,
        ScheduledErrorHandler.class
})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
```

You can register your test configuration class (ExampleScheduledJob) as indicated above. Since it is a static inner class, you need to use it like `SchedulerErrorHandlerTest.ExampleScheduledJob`